# LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape undefined

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, koma-script

First question.
I am quite new to LaTeX (using XeTeX from TeXLive 2015 recently installed and up to date) and I get the following warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf(0)/m/sl' undefined

(Font)              using `EU1/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf(0)/m/n' instead on inpu
t line 136.
```

Line 136. is the last line of a subsection.

I use KOMA-script `srcbook` class and `fontspec` package to use `EBGaramond` font. As far as I can see there is no apparent change of font anywhere, so I would like to have a way to figure out why LaTeX seems to switch from `m/n` to `m/sl` (slanted font if I understand correctly).

Many thanks
Best regards

Joseph

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside=semi,paper=a4,pagesize=pdftex,fontsize=9pt,headinclude=on,footinclude=on,DIV=12,parskip=never]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Contextuals=Alternate,Numbers=OldStyle,RawFeature={+ss02,+cv01,+dlig}}

\newcommand\fontfeatures{RawFeature={+ss02,+cv01,+ss05,+dlig},ItalicFeatures={RawFeature=+cv04,CharacterVariant=5:2}}
\setmainfont[\fontfeatures,Ligatures=Historic]{EBGaramond12-Regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\lettrinefont[\fontfeatures]{EBGaramondSC12-Regular.otf}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\Large}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalsize}

\let\raggedsection\centering

\usepackage{lettrine}

\renewcommand\LettrineTextFont{\lettrinefont}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\automark[subsection]{section}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{.j.}} % avoid empty \rightfirstmark

\newcommand\currentbooks{\ifstr{\leftfirstmark}{\leftbotmark}{\leftbotmark}{\leftfirstmark\enspace---\enspace\leftbotmark}}
\newcommand\currentchapters{Chap \ifstr{\leftfirstmark}{\leftbotmark}%
 {\ifstr{\rightfirstmark}{\rightbotmark}{\rightbotmark}{\rightfirstmark\enspace---\enspace\rightbotmark}}
 {\rightfirstmark\enspace---\enspace\rightbotmark}}

\lehead{\currentbooks}\rehead{\currentchapters}
\lohead{\currentbooks}\rohead{\currentchapters}
\chead{}
\cfoot[]{}\ifoot[]{}\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\section[j. De Moseh/ ou Genese]{Le premier livre de Moseh/\\ {\normalsize dict Genese.}}

\subsection[.j.]{Chapitre premier.}

Dieu crea au com\-men\-ce\-ment le ciel et la ter\-re. Et
la ter\-re es\-toit in\-dis\-po\-see et vuy\-de/ et les te\-ne\-bres
es\-toient sus les aby\-smes/ et le vent de Dieu se demenoit
par dessus les eaues.\\ % special case here for lettrine
Et Dieu dist: Que la lumiere soit faicte/ et la lumiere fut faicte.
Et Dieu veit que la lumiere estoit bonne: \& Dieu separa 
la lumiere des tenebres/ \& appella la lumiere/ jour: et
les tenebres/ nuict. Lors fut faict du soir \& du matin/ le premier jour.

\subsection[.ij.]{Chapitre.ij.}

LEs cieulx donc \& la terre furent parfaictz \& tout lexercite diceulx. Et accomplit
au septiesme jour son oeuvre quil avoit faicte. Et Dieu beneist le septiesme jour et le sanctifia: car
en cestuy avoit cesse de toute son oeuvre quil avoit cree pour estre faicte.

\subsection[.iij.]{Chapitre.iij.}

OR le serpent (que le Seigneur Dieu avoit faict) estoit plus ruse que tous les animaux des champs: lequel dist a la femme:
Voire ? que Dieu ayt dit: Vous ne mangerez point de tout arbre du jardin ? Adonc la femme respondit au serpent: 
Nous mangeons du fruict des arbres du jardin: mais du fruict de larbre qui est au milieu du jardin Dieu a dist: Vous nen mangerez 
point/ \& ne le toucherez point: affin que ne mouriez. Puis le serpent dist a la femme: Vous ne mourrez nullement. Car Dieu scait
que au jour auquel vous en mangerez/ que voz yeulx seront ouvers: \& serez comme dieux congnoissans le bien et le mal.
La femme donc voyant que larbre estoit bon a manger/ et quil estoit plaisant aux yeulx/ \& arbre desirable pour acquerir science/
print du fruict diceluy/ \& en mangea: \& en donna aussi a son mary qui estoit avec elle/ lequel en mangea. Lors les yeulx de eulx deux
furent ouvers/ \& congneurent quilz estoient nudz/ si cousirent ensemble des fueilles de figuier/ \& se feirent des ceinctures.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, line 136 is empty in the source. Happy to provide the source if needed.

Comment: `/sl/` means slanted, i.e. the font `EBGaramond12-Regular` does not have the slanted characters and will use the normal shape for this

Comment: Thanks for the info. I would like to know is what command triggers the slanted ? I've changed many elements to \normalfont (which is EBGaramond-Regular), but it seems some are still using slanted, but there is no easy way to determine this (as least I do not know of any).

Comment: The header uses slanted, that's it.

Comment: I put this before \begin{document} \addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\Large}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont} and still get the warning.

Comment: Hm, should be `\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\normalcolor}`

Comment: Don't let people waste their time by guessing what you are doing. Show a complete minimal example.

Comment: Sorry Ulrike, provided a simple .tex file.

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks, it removes the warning. I'll read again the documentation to try to understand better the difference between \addtokomafont and \setkomafont.

Comment: With `\addtokomafont` you add something, since `slshape` is already there you get the warning, even if `slshape` is overwritten by `upshape` later. With `setkomafont`, you start from scratch.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_B for clarifications, understood perfectly now.

Answer (score 8):

While this doesn't answer the question, you can select the slanted font using something like the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond12-Regular.otf}[
  SlantedFont = EBGaramond12-Regular.otf ,
  SlantedFeatures = {FakeSlant} ,
  ItalicFont  = EBGaramond12-Italic.otf ,
]

hello \textsl{hello} \textit{hello}

\end{document}
```

In fact, you could even load it with a bright colour (`SlantedFeatures = {FakeSlant,Colour=FF0000}`) so that you can see where it gets used.

Personally, I'd avoid a slanted shape and simply load the italic shape instead. Weirdly enough, that (silently substituting slanted for italic) should be default in `fontspec`, so I'm not sure how you're loading the EBGaramond font. You can force it, of course, with:

```
\setmainfont{EBGaramond12-Regular.otf}[
  SlantedFont = EBGaramond12-Italic.otf ,
  ItalicFont  = EBGaramond12-Italic.otf ,
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this removes the warning. But was still wondering what caused the warning in first place (just for curiosity and also to learn). Best, Joseph